# How can I use input HTML with formset in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a formset with 2 fields.
When I run it, display this "/>" on the screen. 
Look above my html code.
I don´t know why this is happen. I think that is something in HTML tag and I have to change it.
I appreciate if someone can help me to solve this situation.
Thanks.

```
HTML:

{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

<script src="{% static 'id15/assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'id15/assets/js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>

<form class=" bd-form-20 " action="" name="form-name" method="POST" >
{% csrf_token %}

           <script>
            function caps(element){
                element.value = element.value.toUpperCase();
            }
            </script>

    <label>outorgado</label><br><br>
          <div>
            {{ formsetoutorgado.management_form }}
            {% for formset in formsetoutorgado %}
              <div class="link-formset">

               <input type="text" id={{formset.nom_outorgado}}  /><br><br>
               {{formset.nom_outorgado.errors}}
               <input type="text" id={{formset.num_cpf_outorgado}} /><br><br>
               {{formset.num_cpf_outorgado.errors}}

              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>


        <script>
        $('.link-formset').formset({
                    addText: 'Adicionar',
                    addCssClass: 'add-row',
                    deleteText: 'Remover',
                    deleteCssClass: 'show',
        });
        </script>

    <br>
    <button type = "submit" >
    Cadastrar e Continuar
    </button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This `<input type="text" id={{formset.nom_outorgado}}/>` is your problem. `{{formset.nom_outorgado}}` is actually the `<input>` field, not the `id` of the form field. So you should either have just:

```
{{ formset.nom_outorgado }}
```

in your HTML (without the surrounding `<input ...>`) or if you want to create your HTML manually:

```
<input type="text" id="{{ formset.nom_outorgado.id_for_label }}" name="{{ formset.nom_outorgado.html_name }}" value="{{ formset.nom_outorgado.value }} />
```

to get the `id` of the field. Don’t forget the `"` around the `id` and to set a `name` and `value` if you want to populate the field from the form. As Daniel commented, this is not why Django was made, the first option is what you should do.

Comment: ... but don't do the second, because if you do the field won't automatically populate with the submitted value, and even more importantly won't submit any data because there is no `name` attribute.

Comment: I include "onkeyup="caps(this)" in input tag "<input type="text" id="{{ formset.nom_outorgado.id_for_label }}" name="{{ formset.nom_outorgado.html_name }}" onkeyup="caps(this)" >" and it worked perfect. Thanks !!!!!

Comment: The next field, I include a mask, but it didn´t work. <... class="form-control cpf-mask" placeholder="999.999.999-99"> <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#num_cpf_outorgado').mask('000.000.000-00');}); </script>